# Apagando Arquivos locais Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript

Basicamente fiz um aplicativo onde o usuário grava um áudio, e então é apresentado a ele com 2 opções, Play e Remover.
Porém minha função de remover não está funcionando e o Logcat nem o debug mostram erro.

Função remover:

```
deleteAudio(){
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
     this.file.removeFile(this.file.documentsDirectory, this.fileName)
   } else if (this.platform.is('android')) { 
    this.file.removeFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory, this.fileName) 
    }
   }
```

Estou fazendo alguma coisa errada?

Chamada da função:

```
<ion-button slot="end" (click)="deleteAudio()">
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
```

Função que funciona o callback:

```
  getAudioList() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("audiolist")) {
      this.audioList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("audiolist")).then( data =>{
        console.log('Funciona');
      }).catch( error => {
        console.log('Erro') ;
      });
      console.log(this.audioList);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa, o removeFile é uma função assíncrona, nesse caso ela retorna uma Promise, tem que esperar o callback da Promise ou usar o async/await, segue as duas formas abaixo:

#### Callback

```js
deleteAudio(){
  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    this.file.removeFile(this.file.documentsDirectory, this.fileName).then( data => {
      alert('Sucesso');
    }).catch( error => {
      alert('Erro') ;
    });
  } else if (this.platform.is('android')) { 
    this.file.removeFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory, this.fileName).then( data => {
      alert('Sucesso');
    }).catch( error => {
      alert('Erro') ;
    });
  }
}
```

#### Async/Await

```js
async deleteAudio(){
  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    await this.file.removeFile(this.file.documentsDirectory, this.fileName)
  } else if (this.platform.is('android')) { 
    await this.file.removeFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory, this.fileName)
  }
}
```

Comment: Ambos métodos não funcionaram e nada aparece nos logs

Comment: Tenta colocar alert nos callbacks, como fiz agora.

Comment: Coloquei, ele não me retorna nada. Fiz um teste colocando um callback em outra função que já está funcionando e deu certo, porém na função de deletar o arquivo não.

Comment: Coloca a chamada e como está a outra função na pergunta.

Comment: Coloquei na edição.

Comment: Tenta fazer sem o if else. Talvez a validação possa não está certa.